How to set the SmallImageSource property?
I'm new in wpf. Now I'm building a wpf project. Below is parts of my MainWindow.xaml:
       <Ribbon.ApplicationMenu>
            <RibbonApplicationMenu SmallImageSource="Resources/Buttons/Export.png">
            </RibbonApplicationMenu>
        </Ribbon.ApplicationMenu>

I can see the icon in design area, but we I try to run it, I always receive error:
can't locate source "Resources/Buttons/Export.png"

Why?

Solved! Properties of the png file must be set!
